# shell scripts to get geolocations from google

Tags: google-maps, shell, google-maps-api-3

I know that there is a way use html5+javascript to query for the geolocation(lantitude and longtitude) of a server's current location with IP. However, i want query for the geolocation(lantitude and longtitude) information of the server via shell script from the server.Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output may be either XML or JSON.

Export to XML

```
#!/bin/bash 
WHERE="athens,greece"
API_KEY=""
curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=$WHERE&key=$API_KEY"
```

Export to JSON

```
#!/bin/bash 
WHERE="athens,greece"
API_KEY=""
curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$WHERE&key=$API_KEY"
```

You may refer to [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, as to whether you want postcodes, or lat/lon or what sort of output you expect, or what sort of input you want to provide, but here is an example:

```
curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Belsize%20+rd,+London&sensor=false&region=uk"
```

So I ask Google to give me the lat/lon and postcode of an address in London and return the result in JSON format like this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Belsize Road",
               "short_name" : "Belsize Rd",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "London",
               "short_name" : "London",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "London",
               "short_name" : "London",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Greater London",
               "short_name" : "Gt Lon",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
               "short_name" : "GB",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "NW6",
               "short_name" : "NW6",
               "types" : [ "postal_code_prefix", "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Belsize Road, London NW6, UK",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.54163579999999,
                  "lng" : -0.1803823
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.5375343,
                  "lng" : -0.1921912
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.5399076,
               "lng" : -0.1870606
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.54163579999999,
                  "lng" : -0.1803823
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.5375343,
                  "lng" : -0.1921912
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: I want to use google api to get the current lan and longitude of the server's current location. I don't know where it is but whenever it call the google api, google api is able to provide the location information.

Answer (score 0):

yes alig you well said.

We can use curl to query google for Geocoding API to find out the location coordinates.

Google's geolocation(lantitude and longtitude) allows the remote query by any of the methods either you can use curl or simple php's file_get_contents.

But we have parse the response that we receive either in JSON or XML based on our request.